# Winsock echo server port

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, winsock

I'm trying to port this simple TCP echo program (https://github.com/mafintosh/echo-servers.c/blob/master/tcp-echo-server.c) under Windows for teaching purposes. 
My adaptation compiles and run, but it doesn't work:

**** EDIT: The listen call was somehow cut out. Thank to Remy ****

The client connects, but doen't get any echo.

Ported code is as follows (error messages are in Italian, but they should be clear nevertheless):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
void on_error(char *s) { fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",s); fflush(stderr); exit(1); }

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    WSADATA wsadata; 
    int server_fd, client_fd, err;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    char buf[BUFFER_SIZE];

    int port = 6666; 
    int risultato = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsadata);
    if (risultato != NO_ERROR)
        {fprintf(stderr,"Errore in WSAStartup");fflush(stderr); exit(1);}

    server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (server_fd < 0) on_error("Non ho potuto creare il socket\n");    
    server.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    server.sin_port = htons(port); 
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); 

    const char opt_val = 1;
    setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &opt_val, sizeof opt_val);
    /** bind & listen **/
    err = bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server));
    if (err < 0) on_error("Non ho potuto fare il bind del socket\n");   
    err = listen(server_fd, 128);
    if (err < 0) on_error("Non ho potuto mettermi in ascolto sul socket\n");
    printf("SERVER LISTENING ON PORT %d\n", port);

    while (1) {
      int client_len = sizeof(client);
      do {
      client_fd = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &client, &client_len);
      } while ( client_fd = SOCKET_ERROR);

      if (client_fd < 0) on_error("Non riesco a stabilire una nuova connessione\n");

      while (1) {
        int read = recv(client_fd, buf, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);

        if (!read) break;
        if (read < 0) on_error("Errore nella lettura dal client\n");

        err = send(client_fd, buf, read, 0);
        if (err < 0) on_error("Errore nella scrittura verso il client\n");
    }
  }

    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Run Wireshark to see what problem is. Or try to run another server (`netcat -L` for instance) on the same port.

Comment: Well, what messages are output?  When you breakpoint with your debugger, does it reach the accept() call?  Does the accept() block, as expected?

Comment: I'm sorry, but 'but it doesn't work: netcat/telnet simply do not connect' is just not good enough.  Do some debugging and tell us what is happening.  You didn't even tell us what messages were output on stdout and 'on_error', (whatever that is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `bind()` to set up the listening port, but you are not calling `listen()` to actually start listening on the port before entering your `accept()` loop.

Once you fix that mistake, your `accept()` loop is broken anyway because it is forcing `client_fd` to `SOCKET_ERROR` even if `accept()` is successful.  Your `while()` condition is using the `=` assignment operator when it needs to use the `==` comparison operator instead.  And you should be checking for `INVALID_SOCKET` instead of `SOCKET_ERROR`.

Now with that said, there are some other things to consider:

- WinSock does not use `int` to represent sockets, it uses `SOCKET` instead, which is a `UINT_PTR`.  When checking for an invalid socket handle, don't use `< 0`, use `== INVALID_SOCKET` instead.
- Most socket functions return error codes via `WSAGetLastError()` (`WSAStartup()` being an exception to that).  Get in the habit of using it, and reporting error codes in your output messages, so you know why things are failing.
- `SO_REUSEADDR` expects a `BOOL` value, not a `char` value.  A `BOOL` is a typedef for `int` and thus is 4 bytes.
- not all socket errors are fatal, so you should not kill your entire server if a `recv()`/`send()` operation fails on a non-fatal error.
- `send()` is not guaranteed to send everything you ask it to send, so you should account for that.
- don't forget to close the accepted client socket when you are done using it.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

void on_error(char *s, int *errCode = NULL)
{
    int err = (errCode) ? *errCode : WSAGetLastError();
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: %d\n", s, err);
    fflush(stderr);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsadata; 
    SOCKET server_fd, client_fd;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    int port = 6666, err; 
    char buf[BUFFER_SIZE];

    err = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsadata);
    if (err != 0)
        on_error("Errore in WSAStartup", &err);

    server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (server_fd == INVALID_SOCKET)
        on_error("Non ho potuto creare il socket");

    memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server)); 
    server.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    server.sin_port = htons(port); 
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 

    /** bind & listen **/
    const BOOL opt_val = TRUE;
    setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)&opt_val, sizeof(opt_val));
    err = bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server));
    if (err == SOCKET_ERROR)
        on_error("Non ho potuto fare il bind del socket");
    err = listen(server_fd, 1);
    if (err == SOCKET_ERROR)
        on_error("Non ho potuto mettermi in ascolto sul socket");

    printf("SERVER LISTENING ON PORT %d\n", port);

    while (1)
    {
        int client_len = sizeof(client);
        client_fd = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &client, &client_len);

        if (client_fd == INVALID_SOCKET)
            on_error("Non riesco a stabilire una nuova connessione");

        bool keepLooping = true;
        do
        {
            int read = recv(client_fd, buf, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);

            if (read == 0)
                break;

            if (read == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                err = WSAGetLastError();
                if ((err != WSAENOTCONN) && (err != WSAECONNABORTED) && (err == WSAECONNRESET))
                    on_error("Errore nella lettura dal client", &err);
                break;
            }

            char *pbuf = buf;
            do
            {
                int sent = send(client_fd, pbuf, read, 0);
                if (sent == SOCKET_ERROR)
                {
                    err = WSAGetLastError();
                    if ((err != WSAENOTCONN) && (err != WSAECONNABORTED) && (err == WSAECONNRESET))
                        on_error("Errore nella scrittura verso il client", &err);

                    keepLooping = false;
                    break;
                }

                pbuf += sent;
                read -= sent;
            }
            while (read > 0);
        }
        while (keepLooping);

        closesocket(client_fd);
    }

    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remy, while there are some interesting points in your code (especially froma a teaching POW), I get a couple of errors; 
First, easy: it should be int sent = send(client_fd, pbuf, read, 0);
Second, less so, I get "closeSocket not declared in this scope"

Comment: There was a missing ')' in 
 setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)&opt_val, sizeof(opt_val);
but, now I get this strange ld error

c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw32\mingw32\bin\ld.exe cannot open output file winsock_srv.exe: Permission denied

which is strange since the C version compiled OK. It is sure a problem on the Dev C++ settings on my part.

Comment: @piffy: I have fixed the missing `)`. The `ld.exe` error has nothing to do with the code. You should ask a separate question about that. First, find out where `winsock_srv.exe` is located (is it under `Program Files (x86)`?) and check your user account's permissions to that folder. Also make sure `winsock_srv.exe` is not running when you try to compile it.

Comment: yes now it works. I had problem with mixing .cpp & .c files. I would like to cite you in the upcoming book for the help, how can I reach you?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but

```
   while (client_fd = SOCKET_ERROR)
```

don't you mean?

```
   (client_fd == SOCKET_ERROR)
```

Comment: While this is indeed a logic mistake, it is not the one that is preventing clients from connecting in the first place. The missing call to `listen()` is.

Comment: That happens. Anyway, they don't get any echo? Try to `printf` what you recieved right after `recv` to be sure that you are really recieving anything. Also zero out your buffer (`memset`) before recieving to not keep bytes from last data.